# Avoid infinite loop in google storage function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I run into an issue with infinite loop in google function. Once again I'm trying to automatically resize an image and stop the function but I can not figure out how to check if the file has been already resized. I found few solution to change the name and then check if the name is changed but problem is that I want to keep the original file name.

Also I have use some exaple file to check if the file has been deleted but that doesn't seems to work either

```
if(object.resourceState === 'not_exists'){
    console.log('File deleted')
    return null
}
```

Please any help is appritiated

```
exports.handler = ((object) => {
const bucket = object.bucket;
const contentType = object.contentType;
const filePath = object.name

const destBucket = storage.bucket(bucket)
const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), path.basename(filePath))
const metadata = { contentType: contentType }

if (!object.contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
    console.log('This is not an image.');
    return null;
  }

if(object.resourceState === 'not_exists'){
    console.log('File deleted')
    return null
}

return destBucket.file(filePath).download({
    destination: tempFilePath
}).then(() => {
    return spawn('convert', [tempFilePath, '-resize', '150x150', tempFilePath])
}).then(() => {
    return destBucket.upload(tempFilePath, 
        {
            destination: path.basename(filePath),
            metadata: metadata
        })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must overwrite the original file, you should check the [generation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.storage.ObjectMetadata#generation) value of the [ObjectMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.storage.ObjectMetadata#metageneration) object delivered to your function in order to figure out if object has already been processed.

Comment: Well but I believe none of them tells anything about resolution. I need to keep the name so I can use same download link for my profile images which is generated when profile image is added

Comment: Also the function still keeps running even if I deleted the file with error in console which should not do it with 
if(object.resourceState === 'not_exists'){
    console.log('File deleted')
    return null
}

Comment: You're free to store additional information about the file in custom metadata to check later as well.

Comment: Please any chance to show me how to add custom metadata and also how to access them to avoid infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

After hours of browsing in google documentation I have finally managed to find a solution here on stackoverflow in similar question by accident.

[Firebase Function - Resize and overwrite existing image on upload to Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45265444/firebase-function-resize-and-overwrite-existing-image-on-upload-to-storage)

I can not believe that some of the google documentations are so useless. Most of them are pretty good though.

Anyone with the power can "mark this question as duplicate"